# jQuery Disable Multiple Dropdowns Not Working

Tags: jquery, html

I have dropdowns for a business to enter their hours.  Each day has a drop down with the ID of hours_dayname_open and hours_dayname_closed.  I also have a checkbox to mark it as closed.  I am using the following jQuery to disable the drop down if it is checked:

```
$("#closed_monday").click( function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#hours_monday_open").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#hours_monday_closed").attr("disabled", true);
    }else{
        $("#hours_monday_open").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#hours_monday_closed").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

However, when the checkbox is selected only the open hours is disabled/enabled...  The closed dropdown seems to be getting ignored.

Comment: You might want to look at the prop() method if you're using 1.7.+

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with 1.4.2 at the moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper attribute, strangely, is `disabled`, not `true`.

```
$("#hours_monday_open").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To enable it, remove the disabled attribute:

```
$("#hours_monday_open").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Since jQuery 1.6, you can use the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) functionality to clear/set this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#closed_monday").click( function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#hours_monday_open, #hours_monday_closed").attr("disabled", "disabled");
      }else{
        $("#hours_monday_open, #hours_monday_closed").removeAttribute("disabled");
      }
    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#closed_monday").change( function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $("#hours_monday_open").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#hours_monday_closed").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }else{
        $("#hours_monday_open").removeAttribute("disabled");
        $("#hours_monday_closed").removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
});
```

It is a simple change to .change() and .click(), just the wrong event.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Yr8Q/2/