# Disable submit if inputs empty jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

Disclaimer: I know there are quite a few questions out there with this topic and it has been highly addressed, though I need assistance in my particular case.

I am trying to check if the input values are empty on keyup then disable the submit button.

My HTML snippet:

```
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have used the example answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614399/disabling-submit-button-until-all-fields-have-values) with some modifications:

```
(function() {
    $('.field input').keyup(function() {

        var empty = false;
        $('.field input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                empty = true;
            }
        });

        if (empty) {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
})()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This was just answered for another question. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671323/jquery-disable-multiple-dropdowns-not-working/9671361#9671361

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/yUQeq/

Comment: You're right, it is working - I have greater issues :(

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would suggest disabling the button by default. I would also look at the length of the `.val()`, not check for an empty string. Lastly, I think `document.ready()` is much more readable than your existing code: Here is the full code:

**HTML**

```
<div class='form'>
  <form>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input id="username" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class='field'>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="password" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class='actions'>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>​
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.field input').on('keyup', function() {
    let empty = false;

    $('.field input').each(function() {
      empty = $(this).val().length == 0;
    });

    if (empty)
      $('.actions input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
      $('.actions input').attr('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/2Cm9p/).

Comment: `empty = $(this).val().length == 0` is not the same with your sample code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and it is not completely correct since the `empty` flag will only depend on the last input value

Comment: great idea mate , but how the same can be achieved for atleast one value is entered ?

Answer (score 2):

I use this in my project and it succes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.field').keyup(function() {

    var empty = false;
    $('.field').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
            empty = true;
        }
    });                   

    if (empty) {
        $('.actions[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('.actions[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }                
  });
});
```