# Disable submit when inputs are empty

Tags: php, jquery, html

http://pastebin.com/wGqMD59N

This is my code. I have tried multiple other methods posted using jquert, but I must have not been writing it correctly. I'm not sure how to apply this to my code. But the second submit button needs to be disabled when the inputs are not filled out.

Comment: if I may , can you try not nesting forms, as it is considered a bad practice

Comment: @Satya: Where do you see form nesting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable submit if inputs empty jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671918/disable-submit-if-inputs-empty-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your "second" button type for `button` instead of `sumbit`.
And I removed the attribute `disabled`.

You need to perform an check on all inputs which resutl will decide if the form has to be submitted or not.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <script>
  $("#button").click(function(){
    var flag=true;

    // check all input values
    $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
        if( $(this).val()=="" ){
            flag=false;
        }
    });

    // submit the form
    if(flag){
        $("form#input").submit()
    }else{
        // You should do something here.
        alert("Please fill all inputs!");
    }
  });
  </script>
```

You should think of what to do if `flag` is false...
Like something to inform the user he has to fill all inputs.

**Note**: Load the jQuery library in your `head` to make it work.

*Comment* on your "naming"...
That may be confusing to use names, classes or ids with `input` or `button`.
Try to use descriptive words that are not the same as methods or HTML tags.
;)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/R5fYUS9t 
I tried to add your code, did I do something wrong because it's not working...

Comment: I edited my answer with an example of what you could do. `alert()` is a JavaScript function to trigger an alert box. There are various ways to inform the user on errors... Depending on what you want to do. `alert()` is the easyiest... A nicer alert can be achieved with [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).

Comment: At the top of the page I am checking to see if the data has been submitted and if it does it shows the data. But now the button does not show the data after submitting. Nor does it get printed to XML. But once I remove your code it works again. Not sure why this occurs.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. Can you please explain in further detail where I am meant to put that line?

Comment: Sorry... I'm getting tired I think. Check for the first line of my edited answer. Just add it.

Comment: I added your edited code once more, but now the button doesn't work once all the inputs are filled, the code above does not execute. Sorry if this is frustrating. I can wait for another answer if :)

Comment: I edited again... This new selector is more precise : `$("input[type='text']")`

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery Function

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  var i=Number(0);
  $('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '')
      i++;
  });

 if(i>0)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```